# Windows 10 - Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, iis-10

While there are quite a few questions on this topic, most of them are very outdated or don't have answers, so I hope it's okay that I create a new one.

I have been running this C# project (Angular front-end with Web API back-end) for a couple of years now and never had this issue until last week or possibly the week before (I was on leave for a few days).

When I debug my project (F5), I get an error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.

- I *am* running VS as Admin and the site itself runs perfectly when accessed, but my debugging no longer works.
- I tried attaching to the    w3p process and got the same error.
- I tried upgrading from VS 2017 to    2019 to see if that helps, but no luck.
- When trying to access the Local Security Policy admin, we got an unspecified error saying that my user does not have rights to open it.

I have been in contact with our IT dept and they want to format my machine, which seems a bit drastic for an access error but their response is that it is an "update we run for windows 10 seems to block users from being admin on their machines".

I would appreciate any assistance because reformatting, as we all know, is a massive task. Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: are you using IIS or IIS Express for debugging? do you have option to test it with IIS Express?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu: I cannot use IIS Express due to the structure of the project relying on specific URLs. I tried that this morning but it was unfortunately not viable.

Comment: VS doesn't automatically run as an Admin.  You need to right click a shortcut to VS and select Run As Admin.  If you are opening a file on a remote machine you need admin rights on both local and remote machine.  You also need to use the dollar sign \\server\c$

Comment: It sounds like the problem is entirely with Windows and whatever tomfoolery your IT department is doing with Administrator rights. Get them to explain to your manager, in writing, why this "update" breaks admin debugging and why a reformat is needed to fix it.

Comment: @jdweng: The shortcut has been updated to run as Admin and even when I manually right-click and run as Admin, the same happens.

Comment: @IanKemp I absolutely agree with you and that's what we've done.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad and see if there are any references to a remote machine.  You may need to add the dollar sign to some of references on a remove machine.